# New file apache 2.4 : 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, authorization

I try to access my new server with Apache 2.4.10
Unfortunately , I came across the "403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server. " page. 
I tried to adapt the rules of 2.4 (from my old file in 2.2)

000-default.conf in sites-available

```
#Configuration module SCGI to sync rTorrent / Rutorrent
SCGIMount /RPC2 127.0.0.1:5000
ServerName http://Adress_Server_Lalie/

#Redirection http > https
<VirtualHost Adress_Server_Lalie:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@kim.sufi
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ServerName http://Adress_Server_Lalie/
        Redirect permanent / https://Adress_Server_Lalie/
</VirtualHost>

#SSL
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost Adress_Server_Lalie:443>

        ServerAdmin admin@kim.sufi
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName https://Adress_Server_Lalie

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]"                 nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown                 downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [7-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
        <Directory /var/www>
                Options All
                AllowOverride All
                AuthName "Private"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                Require user lalie
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/downloads>
                Options All
                AllowOverride All
                AuthName "Private"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                Require user lalie
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex  index.html  index.php  /_h5ai/server/php/index.php
```

Can you help me ? 
Thank you :).

Comment: `Options Indexes` in `<Directory /var/www/>` section

Comment: I try but it's not working :(